# Kasa HS200 Smart Light Switch Wiring Question (multiple neutral wires)

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, smart-switch

I'm trying to install a Kasa HS200 smart light switch into a box that has 2 light switches already: an exterior light and an interior light. I'd like to replace the switch for the exterior light. The house was built in 2021.

I have removed the cover and the switch I want to replace (on the left in the photo below). My question is on the neutral wiring. I see 4 white wires all joined together in some kind of connector. What's the best way for me to connect the HS200 white wire? Do I remove that connector and twist 5 wires together? I have circled the white wires in the photo below.

Edit: After doing some research maybe I just need a 5-way connector? Or cut one white wire and join with a wire nut or 3-way connector?

[image: wiring]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't cut any wires - you don't have enough wire length remaining.  If you needed additional wire to make pigtails, it's time to buy some wire.

You can use any binding technique that is Code certified, however, if you're new to all this, I'd stick to the **Wago 773** or **Ideal In-Sure** push-in type connectors as you're using now.  Even better, the **Wago 221** family of lever-nuts, which we're rather fond of around here.

Don't cut them -- stubbornly pull and twist the wires out.  Wire length is precious.  If a wire is less than 6" from the end of the sheath, that's condemning per Code -- at that point you must either pull more length out of the wall, or more likely re-run the entire cable, drywall busting and all.  Like I say, wire length is precious.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I purchased some Wago 221 connectors (5 and 2-way) which made this job very easy. I was initially concerned about how to get the 4 white wires out of their push-in connector but twisting and pulling at the same time did the trick. And no wires were cut!